# Query to display names for values instead of IDs between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, redash

I have a table with the name of different sports

`Sports` Table

```
id   name
----------
1   None
2   Baseball
3   Basketball
4   Football
```

And another table that associated states and their sports teams, based on the level of play for each sport.

`State_Teams` Table

```
id state     pro_league   minor_league     amateur_league
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  alabama         1           4                1
2  alaska          1           1                1
3  arizona         2           3                4
4  arkansas        1           2                3
```

Instead of only displaying those sports IDs, I'd like to display their name. Ideally, I would create a query so that my output looks like this...

Output

```
id state     pro_league   minor_league     amateur_league
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  alabama        None          Football          None
2  alaska         None          None              None
3  arizona        Baseball      Basketball        Football
4  arkansas       None          Baseball          Basketball
```

I'm having issue changing the IDs to be names for all the columns. So far, I can change the name for only one column. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Join `State_Teams` to `Sports`, three times:

```sql
SELECT
    st.id,
    st.state,
    s1.name AS pro_league,
    s2.name AS minor_league,
    s3.name AS amatuer_league
FROM State_Teams st
LEFT JOIN Sports s1
    ON s1.id = st.pro_league
LEFT JOIN Sports s2
    ON s2.id = st.minor_league
LEFT JOIN Sports s3
    ON s3.id = st.amateur_league
ORDER BY
    st.id;
```